# Extract lines from a file with a value,whose parameter greater than 100, with grep and awk

Tags: awk, sed, grep

I have a file, and I have to create a script with the following output file as per the specifications:

The input file has first 28 lines of header, which have to be included in the output
Some of the lines of the input have a specific parameter ZH:any value (eg ZH:100 or ZH:50). The column where the ZH parameter is present differs from line to line.

My output file should contain the header lines and those lines which contain the ZH parameter with corresponding values greater than 100 (eg ZH:105 , ZH:200 and so on)

The lines which do not contain the ZH parameter are to be omitted.

Comment: Please add samples of the output and input, tell us what was done until now and where you might enlighten you. This is a Unix questions site, not a  script  delivering  service.

Comment: It is not possible to show a sample file here as the files are very big themselves and the lines are too long to post in the comments section.

Comment: The file is a sam file, obtained by alignment to a genome

Comment: I have very little knowledge of linux, hence the question

Comment: @David Then cut the length of the line so that it's manageable, while still allowing someone to properly test a solution against it. You've said nothing about your file apart from that it has a header and fields. We don't even know whether it is comma or tab delimited, or if it follows some known format. In a _comment_ (not in the question), you mention SAM files. Be aware that most people here _don't know what a SAM file is_.

Comment: PG:Z:novoalign AS:i:0 UQ:i:0 NM:i:0 MD:Z:22 ZS:Z:R NH:i:2 HI:i:2 IH:i:2 ZH:i:44 ZL:i:41517962

Comment: This is a truncated line of my file.

Comment: The file is tab-separated

Comment: You can edit your question and add necessary information to it.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because It looks like a homework question.

Comment: @XTian this isn't homework, it's almost certainly work, but homework isn't off topic here.

Answer (score 1):

Use `head` and `grep`:

```bsh
(
# get header
head -n 28 file
# grep lines with ZH value > 100
grep -Ew "ZH:.:[1-9][0-9]{2,}" file
) > outfile
```

Comment: It worked!! Thanks a lot. Could you explain the meaning of {2,} in your line?

Comment: The `{...}` part defines the number of occurrences of a character or group. `{2}` means exactly 2 occurrences, `{2,5}` means between 2 and 5 occurrences, `{2,}` means **at least** 2 occurrences. Note that you need extended regex (`-E`) for it to work.

Comment: You can use [regexr.com](https://regexr.com/49794) for great explanations and for testing.

Answer (score 0):

Without a minimal example, it's hard to guess what you're after...

Anyway, this `awk` script might be helpful if you want to filter lines having `ZH` parameter:

```
awk 'strtonum(gensub(/^.*ZH:.:([0-9]+).*$/, "\\1", "1"))>100' file
```

This prints all lines including a field like `ZH:<one character>:<some number>`.

`gensub` extracts the number associated to `ZH`. Then it is converted to number and compared with the number 100.